# Appointment Management Library for Java

Tags: open-source, java

I need to implement an appointment management system for one module of my project. While it is a hard task to implement from scratch, I wonder if there is any open source library which I can add my spring boot project.

My requirements are like; for given days and time span (like 08:00-17:00) a calendar will be created and be sent to people and they will choose what time they want. All appointments will occur a fixed time (like 30mis or 1hour) which will be given when creating calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created an Android library for scheduling. The library will be very easy to convert from Android to standard Java. If you can't find the perfect library you can fork it and build on it.
Here is the landing page: https://bitbucket.org/warwick/schedule_utils_demo/src/master/
I'll be adding a method to get a list of available slots as a top priority.
It's a new library uploaded late Sept 2018. It comes with an android demo app and is available on the Google Play Store:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.WarwickWestonWright.ScheduleUtilsDemo
Hope this helps.